# Cannot read property "user" of undefined when owner is not visible, crashing the BOT

Tags: discord.js

I have this thing that's going on in my BOT. with this code I get some info from the server the user is on:

```
if (command === `server`) {
    message.react("");
    const owner = message.guild.owner.user.tag;
    const embedServer = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`**:books: Server Info: ${message.guild.name}**`)
    .setDescription(`Some information about the server you're on.`)
    .addFields(
        { name: ':person_raising_hand: ・ Member Count', value: message.guild.memberCount, inline: true },
        { name: ':calendar_spiral: ・ Creation Date', value: message.guild.createdAt, inline: true },
        { name: ':globe_with_meridians: ・ Server Region', value: (message.guild.region).toUpperCase(), inline: true },
        { name: ':crown: ・ Server Owner', value: owner, inline: true },
    )
    .setFooter(`${botnv}`)
    .setColor('#f04747')
    message.channel.send(embedServer).catch(err => message.channel.send(":warning: Error!"));
};
```

And it works just fine when on my private server, but once i test it on one where the BOT can't see who the owner is, it just crashes. I want it to send a message saying it couldn't find them. Everything I've tried hasn't worked. if(!user) return under the const doesn't work, .catch(err) doesn't work aswell. I'm stuck.

Comment: Have you tried `const owner = message.guild.owner;` and then `if(!owner){}`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I'm new to this, so I don't know if you get extra anything for it, but I'l set it as a solution if you'd like to put it as an answer.

Comment: Yep, thanks, just added an answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the owner exists first, rather than getting properties on something that is potentially `undefined`.

I would suggest using this instead:

```js
const owner = message.guild.owner;
if(!owner) {
    console.log("Unable to find owner");
} else {
    let tag = owner.user.tag;
}
```

So to integrate this into your code you could do something like this:

```js
if (command === `server`) {
    message.react("");
    const owner = message.guild.owner;
    if(owner) {
        const embedServer = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**:books: Server Info: ${message.guild.name}**`)
            .setDescription(`Some information about the server you're on.`)
            .addFields(
                { name: ':person_raising_hand: ・ Member Count', value: message.guild.memberCount, inline: true },
                { name: ':calendar_spiral: ・ Creation Date', value: message.guild.createdAt, inline: true },
                { name: ':globe_with_meridians: ・ Server Region', value: message.guild.region.toUpperCase(), inline: true },
                { name: ':crown: ・ Server Owner', value: owner.user.tag, inline: true },
            )
            .setFooter(`${botnv}`)
            .setColor('#f04747')
        message.channel.send(embedServer).catch(err => message.channel.send(":warning: Error!"));
    } else {
        message.channel.send("Unable to find owner");
    }
};
```

Also, one other thing is that you shouldn't need to have brackets around `message.guild.region`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/catch statement & get error & send message to channel

```js
if (command === `server`) {
    message.react("");
    try {
        const owner = message.guild.owner.user.tag;
        const embedServer = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**:books: Server Info: ${message.guild.name}**`)
            .setDescription(`Some information about the server you're on.`)
            .addFields({
                name: ':person_raising_hand: ・ Member Count',
                value: message.guild.memberCount,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: ':calendar_spiral: ・ Creation Date',
                value: message.guild.createdAt,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: ':globe_with_meridians: ・ Server Region',
                value: (message.guild.region).toUpperCase(),
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: ':crown: ・ Server Owner',
                value: owner,
                inline: true
            }, )
            .setFooter(`${botnv}`)
            .setColor('#f04747')
        message.channel.send(embedServer);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error); //Console Log Error
        return message.channel.send(":warning: Error!");
    };
};
```

Learn more about try/catch [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: Whilst this is technically a solution, it may keep failing due to something else, which means it will always just run the catch block.